# Refresh header redirect fails - "the scheme does not have a registered handler"

Tags: php, http, redirect, http-headers, response-headers

I don't know how to debug this problem...
I'm trying to do a redirect with a header:

```php
header('Refresh:5;Location:https://www.google.com/);
exit();
```

but I get the following error:

> Failed to launch 'location:[https://www.google.com/'](https://www.google.com/%27) because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Now I understand that this is related to whether I have sent some output on the screen... but in my case I have verified that it was not with the following example:

```
ob_start();

$validate = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

var_dump(mb_strlen($validate));
```

the result is:

```
**0**
```

how do i know it might be related to other header use:

```
var_dump(headers_list());
```

the result is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.28"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
  [2]=>
  string(50) "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Pragma: no-cache"
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the error due to having established the session? Do I understand that the header or the list of the header is due to having established the session?
2. I don't see how to solve the problem... it's not 1 or 2 or 3 files, it's a lot of files before reaching the redirector?

**NOTE:** I'm trying to use mandatory **header**, it shouldn't use meta tag or javascript.

Comment: Zorry @ADyson i am making a Q&A post because the visibility of this error is hardly noticeable and documented if you realize it is related to php rather than browsers.

Comment: I see. It's not related to php directly though, really. In this case php was used to set the header, but the browser would have a problem with an incorrect header issued by any server or process. It's a http and browser issue, really.

Comment: P.s. your title could be a lot more descriptive.

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry, my mother tongue is Spanish, I thought it would be descriptive enough... to put on the table that this is a rookie question for someone who is starting to develop and doesn't know how to debug something that in this This case is poorly documented... if you can, modify the title... if you can give it a better meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related to header or sending headers or web browser.

Actually, the two questions that a php developer can ask you should be discarded since the problem is a bad documentation in php.

For redirect you must use url instead of Location:

```
header('Refresh:5;url:https://www.google.com/);
```

this is not properly documented on the PHP page, but can be found in a comment below.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114